# How to use regex in Notepad++ to find and replace all strings of repeating "." that are over a certain size?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a document with many lines in this format: `text ........ text`, I want to replace these strings of '.'s with a single ','.

The regular expression `.*.` doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Find `\.{2,}` replace `,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the dot, because it is a metacharacter which matches *any* symbol.

You can literally escape it with backslash, like this, `\.` or use a character class, like this `[.]`.

For replacing sequences of dots of, say, 5 items or more, use `[.]{5,}`

**Note:** You can express "one or more `x`" as `x+` instead of `x*x` to avoid repeating the content of `x`

Comment: How would one concatenate other symbols onto this? Like searching for one or more `.` followed by one or more white space?

Comment: @Sam `[.]+[ ]+` would be an expression for that. Strictly speaking, square brackets around space character are not required, but they make the regex easier to read. You can also use `\s` in place of `[ ]` to match any kind of whitespace (e.g. tabs) along with spaces.

Answer (score 3):

A `.*.` matches any 0+ chars othert than line breaks and then any char other than a line break.

You need

**Find What**: `\.{4,}`
**Replace With**: `,`

The `\.{4,}` will match 4 or more occurrences of consecutive dots.

[image]

**Variations**:

You may use `\h+\K\.+(?=\h)` and replace with `,` if you need to require horizontal whitespace before and after 1+ dots and replace with `,`. Here, `\h+` matches 1 or more horizontal whitespaces, `\K` omits these whitespaces from the match, `\.+` matches 1 or more dots, and then `(?=\h)` positive lookahead tries to assert the presence of a horizontal whitespace after the last dot matched.

An equivalent of the above expression is `(?<=\h)\.++(?=\h)` pattern (where `(?<=\h)` positive lookahead is used to require a horizontal whitespace).

The same result can be achieved with capturing groups: search for `(\h)\.+(\h)` and replace with `$1,$2`.

Note that `+` (one or more repetitions) in these patterns can also be replaced with the [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{min,max}`, where `max` parameter can be missing, just make sure you adjust its values as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try, find by regex: `\.+` or `\.{2,}`
And replace by: `.`